# can a template value inside a struct contain an object?

Tags: c++, templates, object, struct, constructor

If I have a struct like

```
template<typename T>
struct element{
    T val;
};
```

Can val be an object? And if it is possible how can i do that, the compiler tells me
`constructor for element<object> must explicitly initialize the member val which does not have a default constructor`.

Comment: Yes it can, and it's asking you to give whatever you're trying to pass a default constructor.

Comment: It looks like `T` does not have a default constructor, but yes `val` can be an object.

Comment: How would you construct this `object` (or whatever the `T` is that's causing trouble) outside a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can val be an object?

Yes. A demo:

```
element<int> e;
```

The structure `element<int>` contains a member object of type `int`.

> ```
> constructor for element<object> must explicitly initialize the member val which does not have a default constructor.
> ```

`element` as you have defined it will default construct the `val` member. Therefore it requires that `T` is default constructible. This limitation has nothing to do with the fact that `element` is a template, it holds for non-templates as well.

The error message tells you that you have instantiated the template with a type argument that is not default constructible. To support such types, you need a custom constructor for `element`. For example:

```
template<typename T>
struct element{
    T val;

    template<class... Args>
    element(Args&&... args)
    : val(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}
};

// ...

element<non_default_constructible> e(42);
```

---

> what if i can't use c++11?

You could initialize the member by copy. This of course has the requirement that the wrapped type must be copy constructible:

```
template<typename T>
struct element{
    T val;

    element(T other)
    : val(other)
    {}
};
```

Comment: just another question, what if i can't use c++11?